# How can I decrease the size of textures in my blend file programmatically?

Tags: python, scripting, image, optimization

I'm new to blender.

I have a big .blend file and I need to decrease the size of the textures. How can I do it **programmatically**?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/how-to-scale-an-image-with-python

Answer (score 2):

[Asked many times](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42685/how-to-change-image-dimensions-of-a-generated-image-from-python)

To quickly scale all images in .blend to given size:

```
import bpy
for img in bpy.data.images:
    try:
        # for empty render result image, etc.
        img.scale(512, 512) # (width, height)
    except:
        pass
```